# Lighthouse error NO_LCP on single canvas element as leaf node on HTML

Tags: html, css, lighthouse

```html
<html>

<head>
  ...
</head>

<body>
  --- it looks like
  <div>
    <canvas /> <-- only here without another leaf
  </div>
  --- or
  <canvas /> <-- only here without another leaf
  ---
</body>

<html>
```

I tried to add another leaf element and `Lighthouse works well`. But, I'm `facing scale problem on canvas element` that not have render behavior like `div` I just want my single canvas display on my website. So, `I asking for another approach to fix that problem without add another leaf element.`

Answer (score 0):

your code should be

```
<head>
...
</head>

<body>
<div>
  <canvas>

  <canvas />
</div>
--- or
<canvas>

<canvas /> <-- only here without another leaf
---
</body>

<html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Currently `canvas` elements are not eligible as LCP elements. Therefore if your page consists of only this, then no LCP element will be captured.

You can track the request for this here:
https://github.com/w3c/largest-contentful-paint/issues/74

There’s also a suggestion to improve the Lighthouse error message in this case here:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/12309